Issue static wildcard certificate with cert-manager
Is there a way to issue custom static wildcard certificate with cert-manager? We have a wildcard certificate and we want cert-manager to issue all Ingress certificates with this wildcard certificate.
The reason why we don't use static tls secret for Ingress is that we have couple of other domains and in some cases an Ingress is multi-domain which other domains certificate is issued by cert-manager, so to not separate Ingress, we want to use cert-manager.
